# access remote server with provided credential

Tags: ssh, remote-access, remote-server

I need to access a remote server, I got the **IP address**, **hostname** and **password** from the server provider.

With those information, can I make a SSH connection to the remote server? If So, how to config .ssh/config file? (I am using a MacBook)

If I am not able to access the server through SSH with those information, how am I supposed to access the server with those information from server provider?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. It is not enough. You need also the remote username to access the server. Otherwise you should be good with

```
Host alias
  Hostname IP # or given hostname -- should not matter)
  User remote-username
```

and then you should be able to connect using `ssh alias` and get prompted for a password.

Answer (score 0):

The way to access via ssh depends how the server is configured. If the connection is with a password, you would need a user also.

You have instructions here:

https://www.siteground.com/kb/how_to_log_in_to_an_account_via_ssh_in_mac_os/

Port is not needed usually, but just in case the ssh port by default is 22

Good luck!